# Finding unused 'Imports' statements in VB.NET source code

Tags: .net, vb.net, performance, visual-studio

The Visual Studio IDE allows me to scan for unused references in VB.NET source code. But I also have a lot of unused [Imports statements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9st4tss.aspx) in my application.

Two questions:

- Is there a way to find unused `Imports` statements throughout my VB.NET source code?
- Do unused `Imports` statements hurt the performance of my application?

Comment: I know c sharp has a 'remove usings' function when you right click on a using (import). Maybe the vb version has too?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It doesn't hurt runtime performance at all, the only time those [using directives](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) are actually used is at compile time.

The three reasons why you could want to keep your import count low are :

- For clarity sake. Imports are a usefull way to learn at first glance what kind of operations a class is performing : don't waste this opportunity ! (eg if I see a Regex namespace imported on top of a file, I usually assume there's some regex work in it)
- The more imports you have, the more likely you are to run into a name clash (ie having one type name refering to two different types in two different imported namespaces)
- Since those directives are used at compile time, having lots of unused import could hurt buildtime and/or intelliSense performance. (Just speculating here, I don't know how IntelliSense is working behind the scenes)

If you want to get rid of those useless namespaces, I don't think there's any built-in support for that in Visual studio (I assume this is what you meant by "the VB.net IDE"), but you can either use some third party tools (eg [Resharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/)) or some other IDEs (eg [Eclipse.net](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eclipsedotnet/))

Comment: All I would add to this is that quality tools such as Resharper can tell you if they are used (exactly like looking up a code usage). The manual method is to delete one and see if it still builds!!!

Answer (score 3):

I believe this inclusion is done at compile time, and only on demand.

In other words, no performance penalty.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, unused / superfluous imports **do not** affect performance at all because of representing static, compile-time information only.

Second, tools like [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/) exist to help you keep your code more maintainable, ease refactoring, clean-up obsolete stuff like unused imports etc.